Is there an elegant way to handle VERY large numbers?
I am making a python clicker game, and in my art.py file, I handle all numbers from 0-1k. Once the program reaches +999, the format switches from {hundreds + tens + ones} to {thousands + decimal + hundreds}. I want to be able to do this, but for every number leading up to 10^81 (it makes sense, trust). I am okay with making a whole bunch of tedious little statements, but I'd really prefer not to. Is there an elegant way to handle this?

I want to be able to do this, but for every number leading up to 10^81 (it makes sense, trust). No, it doesn't make sense.  At all. 52! is less than 10^69, And that's a HUGE number beyond imagining.  You're talking about values that are 12 orders of magnitude greater than that.  You're talking about numbers that are pushing into the realm of total number of photons emitted in the entire lifetime of the universe.

Have you considered using the decimal package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

What do you mean by "handle"? You want to use SI prefixes? Like a thousand = 1.0k, ten million = 10.0M? A better way to describe that might be "abbreviate". Or do you want to show the exponent? Like a thousand = 1.0e3, ten million = 1.0e7?

"up to 10^81 (it makes sense, trust).": sorry, I don't trust that need yet. That's near the number of atoms in the observable universe. What does your number represent?

@AndrewHenle Think of universal paperclips, or pretty much any other idle/clicker game ever. The reason why I want to get to this specific number, is because its roughly how much matter is in the known universe; which is the end-game goal.

@wjandrea Yes. k, m, b, t, q, qi, etc.

@AndrewHenle Part of the fun with clicker games like Cookie Clicker is the absurd sizes of numbers they use.

have a look at this https://gist.github.com/mrphlip/6073f2fe35b4e2c85b0b033a15865054

thank you @user_na , I think this will work.
